# ASM Bytecode to trace Thread.start() method

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I want to trace, which method invokes java.lang.Thread.start() method. 
How do achieve it using ASM Bytecode Library...?

Comment: You could patch java.lang.Thread and use reflection to find and log the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that highly depends on what amount of code you want to trace:

1. Do you want to know where the classes of your application are calling `Thread.start`: Then you need to instrument all classes of your application.
2. Do you want to know where any class is calling `Thread.start`, including those of the Java standard API: Then you need to instrument `Thread` what is however difficult to achieve.

In order to achieve the (1) goal, you can register a [Java agent (tutorial attached)](http://dhruba.name/2010/02/07/creation-dynamic-loading-and-instrumentation-with-javaagents/) that parses any method of classes that are loaded and checks them for calls to `Thread.start`. Whenever you discover such a method, you need to add some sort of tracing mechanism to these methods as for example a call to `System.out.println`. [ASM has an excelent tutorial](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf) where they even provide a similar example in the chapter on method byte code. Also, you can use the [`ASMifier`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/ASMifier.html) in order to print out what code you actually would have to implement.

The (2) goal is way harder to achieve. In order to get this done, you would have to [redefine the class for `Thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433047/overriding-single-classes-from-rt-jar) which can cause some serious trouble since it is a system class. From within the `Thread` class, you could call `Thread.getStackTrace` and check the name of the method on top of the current call stack which is represented by a `StackTraceElement`. You would then again have to enable tracing this method by for example calling `System.out.println`.

I would recommend you the first strategy since this is easier to make work. Also, you might break the usage license of the JDK, depending on where you run your application.

Comment: Did you hear of [`new Throwable().getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace())? Getting the caller is not that hard (though not recommended for production code).

Comment: I have actually not thought of that. You would however not get hold of the caller instance, just disover its type. Then again, you can find that instance when debugging, so there is probably a way for that using JNI or some API.

Comment: I updated my answer. Thanks for your hint. I tried a little and found `Thread.getStackTrace` to be even easier than creating a `Throwable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own javaagent which transforms all methods. It should search for `java.lang.Thread.start()` invocations and add logging before them.

So, you should inspect all methods and look for the following bytecode instruction:

```
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Thread start ()V
```

and insert something like this before the instruction:

```
GETSTATIC java/lang/System out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
LDC ${current_method_name_and_desc}
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/PrintStream println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Comment: Hi, as you told i have a my own javaagent, but start method is a native method , so if i do tracing of start method, my jvm is crashed. it is working for other methods...is any other way? or Using ASM Native methods cannot be instrumented?

Comment: @RameshSubramanian, you shouldn't transform `start` method itself, but all another method, which call `start`. I'll extend my answer and show the main idea.

Comment: For your information: `start` is not a native method, it is calling `start0` internally which is native. Therefore, instrumenting `start` would hypothetically be possible while not recommended.